# Behavior of readChar() in DataInputStream in Java ?

Tags: java, io, stream

I was doing R&D with DataInputStream and was examining its output in different cases.
I have a file which has a line of text and i am reading it using different methods.
My code is:

```
public class TestDataAgain {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File fileName = new File("againDataIO.dat");

    try(DataInputStream in = 
            new DataInputStream(
                new BufferedInputStream(
                    new FileInputStream(fileName)))) {
        while(in.available() >= 1) {
            System.out.print((char)in.readByte() + " ");
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

When i use casting and readByte() method the output is fine but when I do not do any casting and use `readChar()` as:

```
while(in.available() >= 2) {
    System.out.print(in.readChar() + " ");
}
```

The **output** is a bunch of question marks like this:

```
? ? ? ? ? ? ?
```

The file contains a line as:

```
trying to read
```

Can anyone explain the reason of question marks appearing as output. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I have a file which has a line of text" - written in what way? If this is just a regular text file, you probably shouldn't be reading it with `DataInputStream`, which is really designed for data written with `DataOutputStream` or similar.

Comment: Basically, `DataInput.readChar()` says how the data is expected to be interpreted, but it sounds like your file doesn't have characters written that way...

Comment: It is a file with utf-8 without BOM encoding. I know that there are other ways to do the same thing but the question is for understanding purposes that what is happening under the hood.

Comment: Well did you read the documentation for `DataInput.readChar()`? Does that sound like it's appropriate for UTF-8? Basically the answer to your question is "The code is behaving as documented."

Comment: No i dont have knowledge of encoding schemes. So new to that.

Comment: Right, so now's a good time to read up on that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8